# How to create Openid, Google, Yahoo, facebook, twitter without using Gigya.com in php?

Tags: php, openid, oauth

How can I create a universal login system like stackoverflow?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login in php?

I don't want to use Gigya, because I don't want their branding on my site

Answer (score 3):

There are several Open Source OpenID client libraries for PHP. Check out the [Libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries) page on Openid.net.

Comment: Unfortunately, Facebook is not an OpenID provider, so the StackOverflow engine uses the proprietary Facebook API for that. Microsoft Live ID's are not really usable at all (you can only do very basic authentication), but MS said they will eventually be a provider (they ran a beta and discovered that they had messed up, so they were starting over).

Comment: what is the difference between oAuth, OpenID, OpenSocial...their documentation are really frustrating

Comment: and how to get users information using OpenID, this is so confusing!

Comment: You can't, really. But see http://yz.mit.edu/wp/making-sense-of-openid-oauth-opensocial-google-friend-connect-facebook-connect-and-more/ for a very clear article on what's going on.